# How does the address of R_X86_64_PLT32 computed?

Tags: c++, linker, elf

I am trying to understand how the linking works. I have a simple C++ code

```
#include "a.h"

int Other() { 
  return 1;
}

int SomeFunction() {
  Other();
  Other();
  Other();

  return 0;
}
```

which generates the following Relocation table.

```
$ readelf -r a.o

Relocation section '.rela.text' at offset 0x240 contains 3 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000000018  000900000004 R_X86_64_PLT32    0000000000000000 _Z5Otherv - 4
00000000001d  000900000004 R_X86_64_PLT32    0000000000000000 _Z5Otherv - 4
000000000022  000900000004 R_X86_64_PLT32    0000000000000000 _Z5Otherv - 4

Relocation section '.rela.eh_frame' at offset 0x288 contains 2 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000000020  000200000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 .text + 0
000000000040  000200000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 .text + f
```

It looks like the callsites of Other() functions are all marked as R_X86_64_PLT32 type. When I check the definition of R_X86_64_PLT32, it says L + A - P, where `L` represents the place (section offset or address) of the Procedure Linkage Table entry for a symbol, `A` represents the addend used to compute the value of the relocatable field and `P` represents the place (section offset or address) of the storage unit being relocated (computed using r_offset).

I am not sure what it mean by the place of the PLT for a symbol. My questions are

1. What would be the value of L, A, P for that case?
2. From my understanding, PLTs are used by dynamic objects. Why Other() is marked as PLT32 even when this is just a static function.
3. How to find the PLT of the ELF file and how to find Other() in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert and a little bit late but as far as I understand it newer GCC versions use R_X86_64_PLT32 instead of R_X86_64_PC32 to mark 32-bit PC-relative branches.

"On x86-64, for 32-bit PC-relative branches, we can generate PLT32 relocation, instead of PC32 relocation, which can also be used as a marker for 32-bit PC-relative branches.  Linker can always reduce PLT32 relocation to PC32 if function is defined locally. Local functions should use PC32 relocation." ([Related Commit](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commitdiff;h=bd7ab16b4537788ad53521c45469a1bdae84ad4a;hp=80c96350467f23a54546580b3e2b67a65ec65b66))

So despite the fact that the type of the relocation entry is R_X86_64_PLT32 the linker will still use the R_X86_64_PC32 computation (S + A - P) for the relocation target being modified, where:

- `S` is the value of the symbol (`st_value` of `Elf64_Sym`)
- `A` is the addend (`-4` in your case)
- `P` is the address of the memory location being relocated (the start of the address of the `call` to `Other`)

because `Other` is a local function. So the PLT actually doesn't play a role at all in your case.

If you want to get an overview over all section headers (incl. .plt, .got, .got.plt, ...) you can use `readelf -S` on an EXEC/ DYN elf file (compiled and linked). Or just use `objdump -d <file` which also shows the different sections together with the dump.

I hope that this explains it a little bit.

Short example similar to yours for the sake of completeness (I used C but that shouldn't make a difference):

I have a file `rel.c` that calls the function `Other` within `other.c`. First I compile both files `gcc -c -o <name>.o <name>.c`.

`readelf -r rel.o`:

```
Relocation section '.rela.text' at offset 0x198 contains 1 entry:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000000015  000500000004 R_X86_64_PLT32    0000000000000000 Other - 4
```

As you can see the `A` (addend) is `-4` the final addresses `S` and `P` are not known yet.

After linking everything using `gcc -o main rel.o other.o` I used `objdump -M intel -d main` to get the complete dump of the binary.
The interesting part is shown below.

```
...
0000000000001139 <main>:
    1139:   55                      push   rbp
    113a:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
    113d:   48 83 ec 10             sub    rsp,0x10
    1141:   89 7d fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
    1144:   48 89 75 f0             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rsi
    1148:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
    114d:   e8 07 00 00 00          call   1159 <Other>
    1152:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
    1157:   c9                      leave
    1158:   c3                      ret

0000000000001159 <Other>:
    1159:   55                      push   rbp
    115a:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
...
```

As one can see the `DWORD` at `0x114e` holds the offset `0x7` that can be used together with the `IP` to jump to the address of the `Other` subroutine (`0x1152 + 0x7` = `0x1159`).

This is calculated using `S + A - P` = `0x1159 - 0x4 - 0x114e` = `7`.

Comment: Why is the Addend -4 in this case?

Comment: Uff it has been a while since I posted this but I think it's just the number of bytes used to encode the offset. In other words, the distance form `0x11fe` to the next instruction.